# Are there constraint problem calculators?

Tags: optimization, recreational-mathematics, finance, applications

So I just remembered Lincoln Logs exist, so I found ten giant sets of them on ebay for Buy It Now, and I'm trying to decide what combination of purchases gives me the most logs for the least money if I'm going to purchase $n$ sets.

Then I remembered this is exactly the sort of thing I learned in algorithms class, but I really don't want to set this up myself. Much, much too lazy on this rainy day. Are there any online or downloadable calculators which let me set it up easily?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking exactly, but I will vote this up if only for Lincoln Logs. Could you comment on the 'giant'ness of the sets? Are they equally huge? Are you having some combination of bidding and buying now?

Comment: Given that I am purchasing $n$ sets of logs which have {cost, number of logs} from the set ( {20, 120}, {45, 300}, {30, 220}, etc ), which $n$ sets should I purchase in order to maximize the ratio of logs acquiredd to money spent?

Comment: Optimization problem! That's what it is. They're all "Buy It Now".

Comment: Ah, okay. Then I suppose you're going to first set a budget for logs, then minimize the average logs.  You could look at all combinations of ${c_i,l_i}$, where you take the values $i$ from the set $[1,\ldots,n]$, and try to maximize the sum of the $l_i$ over the sum of the $c_i$.

Comment: That's only slightly hard to follow as a comment. Only slightly.

Comment: Oh dear I failed to close my `$` and everything went to hell. What I said (roughly) is set a budget $C$ and find all combinations of $c_i$, the price of a set of logs, such that $\sum c_i\leq C$. Then you take $\sum l_i$ divided by $\sum c_i$ and try to maximise that for each combination.

Comment: @FrankMcGovern, your unclosed comment is messing up the page. Please delete it.

Comment: @Gerry I can't. Please someone flag it for deletion.

Comment: OH GOD IT'S LIKE A NIGHTMARE

Comment: But seriously I think this is a site bug that needs to be MetaSO posted, so don't just delete it-- all of the comments under this question are going beyond their assigned HTML element and overlapping into the community bulletin, at least on my screen.

Comment: @FrankMcGovern, OK, I flagged it.

Comment: @FrankMcGovern: it's fixed.

Comment: @robjohn Hurray. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The search term you want is "Knapsack Problem".

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

There are some interactive ones online,

https://www.google.com/#q=knapsack+problem+solver

As you remembered, this is in principle equivalent to CSP's, or any other NP-complete problem.

Answer (score 0):

For each set, you can figure the logs/money ratio.  Can you buy multiples of one type?  If so, just buy as many as you want of the best.  If not, buy the best one, and keep going down until you have spent as much as you want.  If you have some money left over, look down to see if any small cheap sets are out there and think about those.

Comment: Maximizing (logs per money) can be in tension with maximizing (money spent), though.

Comment: @zyx:  If you want to maximize money spent, buy them all.  If the best logs per money is outside your budget, exclude it and go on to the next.  There could be an issue if the best logs/money almost exhausts your budget and all you can afford after that is a bad bargain.  Say you are offered $(100,50), (60,31),(58,31),(3,10)$ and have $62$ to spend.  You can get $118$ taking the middle two and only $103$ taking the top and bottom.  But you can get $100$ and still have $12$ in your pocket, which might be the best choice.  These problems are theoretically hard and practically easy.

Comment: The greedy algorithm attains at least half the optimum result (given unlimited inventory).  I was thinking of situations where buying one unit of the most efficient thing eats up 51 percent of the budget, but there are several nearly as efficient things that each cost 49.9 percent of the budget, and nothing else to buy.  Buying the best thing first blocks the ability to buy much more of a nearly as good thing.

Comment: @zyx: you are right, that could happen.  If the number of choices is small, as here, it will be obvious what is going on.  You can assess a small number of alternatives and see the best answer depending on your priorities.

Comment: Well, if you believe the market drives the prices to some sort of equilibrium, then real-life optimization should be complicated, with obvious imbalances already having been accounted for.  I grant that this is often violated.